# How to prevent/ignore a field being sent during a nexus graphql mutation of relation field?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server, nexus-prisma

I use combination of Apollo Server, Nexus and Prisma for my graphql server. I wanted to create a user with multiple posts. But the user shouldn't be allowed to set the isPublished field in the posts. When creating the post directly I can use **computedInputs** but Im not sure how to get this on relational create.

How do I throw error or ignore the isPublished property passed?

```
Prisma Schema:

model User {
  id       Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  name     String
  email    String
  posts    Post[]
}

model Post {
  id          Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  content     String
  isPublished Boolean
  user        User?   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId      Int?
}



Nexus Mutation Definitions

const User = objectType({
  name: "User",
  definition(t) {
    t.model.id();
    t.model.email();
    t.model.name();
    t.model.posts();
  },
});

const UserMutation = extendType({
  type: "Mutation",
  definition(t) {
    t.crud.createOneUser({
      alias: "createUser",
      inputs: {
        posts: {
          relateBy: "create",
        },
      }
    });
  },
});



Graphql Mutation

mutation createNewUser {
  createUser(
    data: {
      name: "User1"
      email: "user1@mail.com"
      posts: {
        create: {
          content: "New Content"
          isPublished: true
        }
      }
    }
  ) {
    id
    name
    email
  }
}
```